# How to authenticate to Github from Git Extensions with access token?

Tags: git, authentication, github, oauth, git-commit

I try to push branch with Git Extensions to GitHub, but when pushing the change it displays a Github pop-up window to login.

When pushing repo changes from Git Extensions, it displays a Github pop-up window to login.

I created access token as @invzbl3 suggested, so it should work, but I still get a Github pop-up login screen.

I created access token on Github.com / Settings Developer settings / Personal access tokens / Tokens (classic).

I checked:

- repo checkboxes (Full control of private repositories)
- workflow
- read:org

Is there any else permission needed to push into a Github repo?

I added the token I got into Git Extensions / Tools / Settings / Plugins / GitHub / OAuth Token (Global for all repositories).

Unfortunately this does not authenticate, still displays a Github pop-up window to login.

Comment: Are you adding your SSH into your account on GitHub? https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account#adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-account

Comment: I don't quite understand the connection between the `merge` and the `github login`, but on the login window instead of a password, try entering an `access token`.

Comment: @invzbl3: Access token was a good start. I created new access token on Github.com / Settings Developer settings / Personal access tokens / Tokens (classic). I checked repo checkboxes (Full control of private repositories), nothing else. I added the token I got into Git Extensions / Tools / Settings / Plugins / GitHub / OAuth Token (Global for all repositories) .

Comment: @ViaTech I already added SSH key to Github. My problem is to access Github from Git Extensions with token. I do something wrongly, does not authenticate when pushing to repo.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
The repo had HTTPS URL set, not SSH.

After setting up an SSH address for the repo, the push worked fine as it should.